# Update ParentKEY as DocID from the previous row for parentKey

Tags: sql, parent-child

I have a table that contains parent/child rows.

There are some records that are missing ParentKey which I would like to update.

The logic is that for each BatchID, the rows are order by PosinBatch.
LevelNum = 1 is the Parent row
ParentKey is what makes that row child of the row where ParentKey = DocId.

There are some instances where ParentKey = 0 and LevelNum=0

I need to update ParentKey for those records to the immediate above docId where LEvelNum=1 and BatchId is same.

If you run this script below, then you'll see that

```
BatchID     DocID     LevelNum     PosInBatch     TypeName      ParentKey
22823       45        1            770            Transaction   0
22823       46        0            780            Record        0
22823       48        0            790            Other         0
22823       49        0            800            Other         0
```

For the last 3 rows, the ParentKey would be 45

Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPBATCH (
BatchID INT NULL,
DocID INT NULL, 
LevelNum INT NULL,
PosInBatch INT NULL,
TypeName VARCHAR (50),
ParentKey INT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,31,1,550,'Transaction',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,32,0,560,'Record',31);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,33,0,570,'Record',31);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,35,0,580,'Other',31);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,45,1,770,'Transaction',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,46,0,780,'Record',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,48,0,790,'Other',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,49,0,800,'Other',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,50,1,900,'Transaction',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (22823,51,0,910,'Record',50);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,102,1,710,'Transaction',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,103,0,720,'Record',102);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,110,0,780,'Other',102);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,111,0,790,'Other',102);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,112,1,890,'Transaction',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,121,0,901,'Record',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,115,0,910,'Other',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,116,0,920,'Other',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,122,1,1060,'Transaction',0);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,123,0,1070,'Record',122);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,125,0,1080,'Other',122);
INSERT INTO #TEMPBATCH VALUES (32893,141,0,1082,'Other',122);
```

I tried self joining the table but I am not able to loop through to update all the rows.

Current data looks like this.

```
BatchID     DocID       LevelNum    PosInBatch  TypeName            ParentKey
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------- -----------
22823       31          1           550         Transaction         0
22823       32          0           560         Record              31
22823       33          0           570         Record              31
22823       35          0           580         Other               31
22823       45          1           770         Transaction         0
22823       46          0           780         Record              0
22823       48          0           790         Other               0
22823       49          0           800         Other               0
22823       50          1           900         Transaction         0
22823       51          0           910         Record              50
32893       102         1           710         Transaction         0
32893       103         0           720         Record              102
32893       110         0           780         Other               102
32893       111         0           790         Other               102
32893       112         1           890         Transaction         0
32893       121         0           901         Record              0
32893       115         0           910         Other               0
32893       116         0           920         Other               0
32893       122         1           1060        Transaction         0
32893       123         0           1070        Record              122
32893       125         0           1080        Other               122
32893       141         0           1082        Other               122
```

Here's how I would like the parentKey to look for the ones that are missing.

```
BatchID     DocID       LevelNum    PosInBatch  TypeName            ParentKey
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------- -----------
22823       31          1           550         Transaction         0
22823       32          0           560         Record              31
22823       33          0           570         Record              31
22823       35          0           580         Other               31
22823       45          1           770         Transaction         0
22823       46          0           780         Record              45
22823       48          0           790         Other               45
22823       49          0           800         Other               45
22823       50          1           900         Transaction         0
22823       51          0           910         Record              50
32893       102         1           710         Transaction         0
32893       103         0           720         Record              102
32893       110         0           780         Other               102
32893       111         0           790         Other               102
32893       112         1           890         Transaction         0
32893       121         0           901         Record              112
32893       115         0           910         Other               112
32893       116         0           920         Other               112
32893       122         1           1060        Transaction         0
32893       123         0           1070        Record              122
32893       125         0           1080        Other               122
32893       141         0           1082        Other               122
```

Comment: Is that really a `minimally` reproducible amount of data? That's a lot of rows. Do you really need 350 rows to demonstrate the issue, or could this replicated with perhaps a dozen rows?

Comment: @Isolated - Agreed.  There wasn't a need to provide 350 rows of examples.  I've reduced the number of examples. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result, i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh - I have updated the original message.  Thank you for looking into this.